# Converting an array into a usable string - cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, formhelper

I'm working on a simple cakePHP form. I have a variable $user_name that's populated from my SQL tables.

I've affirmed with

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($user_name);
    echo '</pre>';
```

That the $user_name is correctly populated. I'm trying to use the variable that I've populated to auto-fill the following form field

```
    echo $this->Form->input($modelNameField . '.name_of_customer', array('readonly'=> 'readonly','label'=> 'Customer Name', 'type'=> 'text', 'value'=> $user_name));
```

However, the field remains blank. Any suggestions?

Declaration for $user_name

```
         App::import('model','customerInfo');            
         $customerInfos = new customerInfo();        
         $user_name = array();
         $user_name =  $customerInfos->get_name($id);
```

--

The get_name method

```
         public function get_name($id)
     {
    return $this->find('first', array('fields' =>array('usr_name'),'conditions'=>array("customerInfo.id"=>$id)));
     }
```

--

The print out from print_r($user_name); for $id =1 is

```
         Array
         (
         [CustomerInfo] => Array
         (
          [usr_name] => Ted Jones
         )

         )
```

Comment: Is that code the exact same thing you have in your view? You need to escape the `'` in the label if that's so. Also, what do you mean by that PS? the username is an array? You should pass it as a string to the value.

Comment: Oops, yeah it was supposed to be Customer Name.

Comment: I guess passing it as a string to value is where I'm having the issue. I've tried implode and array_pop and yet no dice.

Comment: Well then, first try setting a value like "Smith" (hardcoded) to the input an see if the field is still blank. If it's not, then you need to update the question, since this wouldn't be a matter of form helper, rather than "how to turn this array into a the string I want to use"

Comment: Fair enough. Tried it and got it work. Updating question.

Comment: ... you need to put an example of the user_name, a simple `array()` doesn't gives much to work with

Comment: `echo $this->Form->input($modelNameField . '.name_of_customer', array('readonly'=> 'readonly','label'=> 'Customer Name', 'type'=> 'text', 'value'=> $user_name['CustomerInfo']['usr_name']));`

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Could you perhaps explain why, for future reference?

Comment: Going to answer trying to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty basic question.

The value option of the form helper needs to be a string, inputs don't know what to do with something like an array.

Your array has this structure

```
$user_name = array (
               'CustomerInfo' => array(
                   'usr_name' => 'Ted Jones'
               )
             );
```

So the string value you want is in `$user_name['CustomerInfo']['usr_name']`. The form helper has no way of knowing that the string you wanted to put as value was in that part of that array.

Don't know why you tried doing an `array_pop` before doing an index definition. Accessing values inside an array in php is quite simple, so try to do the simple approach first and go for the `array_` php functions if it's something more complicated.

For future reference, if you have an array or a variable and you want to use a value inside of it, do a debug or print_r to know how to access it. And if it's a matter of what types of data an option can take, the [cake docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html) are a very good reference.